# Why would a UINavigationController's toolbarItems refresh 4-5 seconds after the rest of the view?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I do have the code for this, but since it's in so many files, I'll only narrow it down and post it if necessary. I believe I might just be missing some method call or thread thing... I have a navigation controller with a table view as its view and a toolbar with three buttons.

1. Touching one of the three buttons causes a method to be called that changes the table view's dataSource, reloads the table, and also changes the titles (and possibly number) of buttons on the toolbar (# of buttons can be 0~3).
2. There is also a rightBarButtonItem that pushes on a modal vc which, upon dismissal, changes the dataSource and reloads the table and buttons as well.

The problem: touching a button (#1) causes immediate effects: the buttons are redrawn with new titles and the tableView's data reloaded. But when the modal vc is dismissed (table's setter properties should cause data to be reloaded before viewWillAppear of the table vc), everything is fine except for the buttons! The correct number of UIBarButtonItems appear on the toolbar, but their titles are blank. I NSLog'd inside the method that sets the toolbarItems property, and after the log says "UIBBI array set", the buttons appear, with [blank] titles, then 4-5 seconds later, the titles appear (long after the method to set them has returned).

Do I need to be doing something in a different thread? Pushing this tvc on has no problems, and the method described in #1 also does not produce the same blank-then-titled effects... So, I'm stumped. Sorry for the LENGTHY explanation...trying to be complete. But any help would be very appreciated!

**Code which is called when the self.resultsArray is updated (from this view, the previous one which pushes it on, or the modal**:

```
- (void)updateBestGuessesButtons
{
if (self.resultsArray.count == 0 || self.resultsArray.count == 1 || !self.bestGuesses)     {
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    return;
}

[self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];

NSMutableArray *toolbarItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                                                       initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace 
                                                                       target:nil 
                                                                        action:nil], nil];
for (NSString *guess in self.bestGuesses) {
    UIBarButtonItem *button = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                               initWithTitle:guess 
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered 
                               target:self 
                               action:@selector(removeWordsWithLetter:)];
    [toolbarItems addObject:button];
}
[toolbarItems addObject:[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                         initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace 
                         target:nil 
                         action:nil]];

[self setToolbarItems:toolbarItems animated:YES];
```

}

Comment: Post the code in which you set/create the buttons please.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have to set the title of the UIButton for all states,

```
[myButton setTitle:@"Foo" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[myButton setTitle:@"Foo" forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
[myButton setTitle:@"Foo" forState:UIControlStateSelected];
// .. and so on
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response! However, these are actually UIBarButtonItem buttons, not UIButtons. Also, I create them each time they are "updated". That is, my "update" method actually creates a new array of UIBarButtonItems that have been created with alloc-initWith...title: and then added to the array, and toolbarItems property set to that new array. I never "change" the titles of the existing buttons. Any other ideas? Thanks so much!

Comment: Update: I changed the [self setToolbarItems:animated:] to self.toolbarItems. When I return from the modal vc with this code, the frame where the toolbar should be is BLACK and then after a 4~5s delay, shows up with fully-titled UIBBIs. Stumped.

Comment: It's the animation probably. The sequence of events after the modal view disappears to expose your view are probably 1) view gets rendered - due to some reason at that time the buttons are not in the view hierarchy 2) the buttons are added to the view hierarchy 3) view is again rendered when certain animations started with Step 1 finishes. Could you double check your animations?

Comment: Having same issue -- 4-5 second delay for my toolbaritems to actually show up -- did you get anywhere with this?

Answer (score 0):

OK -- my resolution to this issue was to move the button creation to the viewDidLoad event.